# C++, should I call destructor?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

In c++ I have a class which allocated memory using `new[]` so I wrote the destructor as following:

```
Matrix::~Matrix() {
    delete[] data;
}
```

My `Matrix` class contains field called `complex` which is a member of a class `Complex` that I wrote.

my question is, should I call the destructor for `complex` too, and how?

Comment: If you have defined a destructor within the `Complex` class, when your `Matrix` object gets destroyed, the destructor for the owned complex object will be called automatically.

Comment: See the section marked [destruction sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) for details on how objects and their members are destroyed.

Comment: "should I call the destructor for `complex` **too**" -- this is a bit of a misconception. The code doesn't call the destructor for `data`. It **deletes** `data`. If you `new` it you `delete` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the destructor of the outer class calls the destructors of inner data members.

If you compile and run the following code, u will see that the destructor of `A`, the class of the inner data member, is called although it hasn't been called explicitly in `B` destructor

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    ~A(){
        std::cout << "A des\n";
    }
};
struct B{
    A a;
    ~B(){
        std::cout << "B des\n";
    }
};
int main(){
    B b;
}
```

The out

```
B des
A des
```

Comment: Be careful with words like "outer" and "inner"; Java folks assume that they have a rather specific meaning, but in C++ they're just ordinary words and, in this case, pretty much noise. Objects have data members. When an object is destroyed, its destructor destroys its members. +1.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is, should I call the destructor for complex too, and how?

No, you do not have to call the destructors. That's the whole point of `new`/`delete`; they call the constructors/destructors.

---

Having said that, and considering it seems like you're new to C++, it's strongly advised to use `std::vector<Complex>` or `std::unique_ptr<Complex[]>` instead of raw pointers. Some of the reasons are:

- Less likely to leak/double free; ownership is obvious.
- Will not do erroneous "shallow" copy of pointers if you forget to add a copy constructor.
- You don't have to worry about `delete`/`delete[]` mismatch.
- `vector` can be resized/copied more easily.
- In general provide an easier to use, harder to abuse, more encapsulated interface.